# jQuery hover toggleClass not working

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a fairly straightforward setup. I have a div on my page that has a box-shadow applied to it using the CSS :hover pseudo class. Within that div is a button (another div). I want to use jQuery to remove the box-shadow on the parent div when a user hovers over the button. I think my jQuery looks right, but it's not functioning. There are no console errors.

Here is my HTML for the box with the button:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-btn">Click Me!</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS that should be toggled on the parent div:

```
.no-box-shadow {
    box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.content-btn').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('.no-box-shadow');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('.no-box-shadow');
    }
);
```

I've also tried this configuration:

```
$('.content-btn').hover(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('.no-box-shadow');
    }
);
```

Comment: Remove the period. `.addClass('no-box-shadow')` not `.addClass('.no-box-shadow')`. Same for removeClass.

Comment: Still not working without the period.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6kvb9gj4/

Comment: I think I figured it out. I wrapped the whole thing in a `$(window).load(function() { block })` and now it's working like a charm. I think perhaps the problem was that the function tried to bind an event listener to the div before it was rendered, since the div is rendered after the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

In your second code, you can change:

```
$('.content-btn').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('.no-box-shadow');
}
);
```

to

```
$('.content-btn').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('no-box-shadow');
}
);
```

And check out this documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to find more about the function and its use.